# How does ruby's rb_raise stop the execution of the c function calling it?

Tags: c, ruby, raise

If you write a ruby method as a function in C that uses `rb_raise`, the part of the function after the call will not get excecuted and the program will stop and you will think that `rb_raise` used `exit()`. But if you rescue the exception in ruby, like:

```
begin
  method_that_raises_an_exception
rescue
end
puts 'You wil still get here.'
```

The ruby code will go on, but your function will stop excecuting. How does `rb_raise` make this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably it uses `setjmp` (before the method is called) and `longjmp` (in `rb_raise`).